# Can a downcast to a derived class with no data members be done in C#?

Tags: c#, casting

I'm attempting to make a wrapper using inheritance.  In reality I am working with de-serialization code that has very generic names and I am looking to save a few keystrokes over the method that wraps an inner object.

```
public class Base
{
  public string Foo { get; set; }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
  public string Bar { get { return this.Foo; } }
}

Base base = new Base();

Derived d = (Derived)base;
```

I get an error trying to downcast.  Is this type of thing possible in C#?  There's no additional data in the derived class so my C++ brain is telling me a downcast is possible...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope.  Class identity is determined by more than just data layout (and that's true in C++ too for non-POD types).

You might want to look into using extension methods to add additional functionality that doesn't require storage of additional data.

Comment: thanks, I never thought of using extension methods with no parameters before.  re: C++ - I think I was recalling times that I might have used knowledge of data layout to do explicit C-style casts but that has nothing to do with inheritance..